# How to check the entity attribute name match, and rewrite(update) data for another attributes?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm using Core Data entity with attributes, here is generated subclass code:

```
extension City {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<City> {
        return NSFetchRequest<City>(entityName: "City")
    }
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var description: String?
    @NSManaged public var temp: Double
    @NSManaged public var temp_max: Double
    @NSManaged public var temp_min: Double
}
```

I'm parsing JSON data and handle it through Weather model, and save the data into the database using this code (it's work well):

```
func saveWeatherData() {

        let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = ad.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let city = City(context: context)

        city.name = Weather.locationName!

        city.description = Weather.details!

        city.temp = Weather.temp

        city.temp_min = Weather.tempMin

        city.temp_max = Weather.tempMax

        ad.saveContext()
    }
```

The question is... how can I check the coincidence of city names (name attribute)? and if such a city already exists in the database, instead of creating a new record, overwrite (update) the values of current attributes (description, temp, temp_max, temp_min)?
Thanks.

Comment: You will need to try and fetch the potential matching city first and create a new one if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm fetching existing data, but how to update the attributes values if I have a match??

Comment: Simply update the attributes of the `City` you retrieved and save the context.

Comment: I'm not sure about my fetchRequest code, could you please give an example of code , how in this case try and fetch the potential matching city and create a new one if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to try and fetch an existing object. If the fetch succeeds, update its properties.  If a match isn't found then create a new object.  Something like:

```
func saveWeatherData() {

    let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = ad.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<City> = City.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"name = %@",Weather.locationName)

    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1  

    do {
       let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
       let city = result.first ?? City(context: context)

       city.name = Weather.locationName!
       city.description = Weather.details!
       city.temp = Weather.temp
       city.temp_min = Weather.tempMin
       city.temp_max = Weather.tempMax

       ad.saveContext()
    }
    catch {
        print("Error fetching city: \(error.localizedDescription)"
    }
}
```

Comment: @rurom, If my answer helped you, I would appreciate it if you could accept it by clicking the tick next to it.